# When trying to deselect with Shift + Click, Blender instead selects the objects that are behind

Tags: objects

Selecting objects that are behind is useful in some scenes, but once I have a group of objects selected, and I again select a selected object, I think the expected behavior should be to deselect that object, not to add more selection.
Is there a way to avoid this or is there a shortcut or something to tell Blender that I actually want to deselect *that* object and not add to selection with those behind?

Comment: Depneding on the scene, it can be tricky. If the objects are small enough I use Circle select (shortcut C) and middle mouse click to deselect.

Comment: Sometimes I'll use Gorgious's method or I'll Ctrl Click in the outliner

Comment: Ctrl click in the outliner is Select Additional, and shift click is Select Range.  However, in the viewport Ctrl click does nothing??  It appears to be just a regular click, and Shift click is select additional instead.  Why?

Comment: @AllenSimpson apparently Blender has the priority on **add** to selection instead than remove from selection, and as it finds more objects behind, it adds them. It's just a matter of priorities. Maybe there is a setting in the preferences for this, I don't know. But surely working in a closed space is frustrating. I already made the walls unselectable, but there is more stuff around.

Comment: Consider local view with the / key

Comment: Ye I was selecting the objects to go in isolate mode but I have no chance XD

Answer (score 1):

This is the behavior of *Toggle Selection* property of *select*, you can only change this by code.

But you can easily deselect an object in a crowded scene using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd>, then choose the object to deselect in the menu.

You can also select a specific object in a tricky scene using <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd>.